# Django model force capitalizing db_column names

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

I'm creating a Django model that reads from an Oracle SQL database. From the table that the model reads from, some columns have mixed cases and spaces, i.e. "Region" and "Foo Bar". So

```sql
SELECT "Region", "Foo Bar" FROM some_table
```

is perfectly valid on the db side of things. The Django model reads those columns explicitly using the `db_column` field,

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  region = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="Region")
  foo_bar = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="Foo Bar")
```

When Django goes to the database, however, I get the error

```
ORA-00904: invalid identifier: "some_table"."FOO BAR"
```

from column name being capitalized somewhere along the process. Is there some way that I can force Django to preserve the mixed case from the Django perspective, without modifying the column names on the db side?

I have tried: `db_column="'Foo Bar'"`, `'"Foo Bar"'`, `"\"Foo Bar\""`, none of these seem to make the string interpreted literally and upper-cased.

Thanks! Hacky workarounds welcomed.

Comment: This smells like a bug, specially if you look into [this test](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fcfe5361e5b8c9738b1ee4c1e9a6f293a7dda40/tests/custom_columns/models.py). What version are you using? Maybe this was fixed in a later version.

Comment: It seems it's by design for Oracle: [see the code that does it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fcfe5361e5b8c9738b1ee4c1e9a6f293a7dda40/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py#L331)

Answer (score 2):

When using an Oracle database, Django changes the column names to uppercase ([see code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fcfe5361e5b8c9738b1ee4c1e9a6f293a7dda40/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py#L331)).

Solving that is not easy. Your best bet is probably extending the Oracle to override this functionality. To do so you need to make a module for your new backend with a file named `base.py`. The contents of which would look like:

```py
from django.db.backends.oracle.base import DatabaseWrapper as OracleWrapper
from django.db.backends.oracle.operations import DatabaseOperations as OracleOperations

class DatabaseOperations(OracleOperations):
    def quote_name(self, name):
        # Modified version that doesn't apply upper to the quoted column names
        if not name.startswith('"') and not name.endswith('"'):
            name = '"%s"' % truncate_name(name.upper(), self.max_name_length())
        return name.replace('%', '%%')


class DatabaseWrapper(OracleWrapper):
    ops_class = DatabaseOperations
```

`DatabaseWrapper` is a special name and you should not change it. After that, you need to set the module as your database engine; you have to go to the parent module (i.e. if the file path is `myapp/backends/custom/base.py` you should set it to `myapp.backends.custom`).

I haven't got time to properly test this code (I don't actually have an Oracle database to play with) but this is how [GIS backends](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/gis/db/backends) are made, so it should be fairly safe (but it may need some other things).